# How to use JSON with unknown multiple keys (PHP)

Tags: php, json, key

I am receiving a JSON String, which has multiple unknown keys. It's pretty hard to explain, because those JSON strings are pretty large, I'll try to break them down in the most efficient way.

I use PHP to break down the object, that I get, when I decode the JSON string.

```
$data1 = $json->result->map->12313214654[0]
$data2 = $json->result->map->12313214654[2]

$differentdata1 = $json->result->map->12313214655[0]
```

As you can see, there are different subsections after the *map* key.
Those are numbers, that are pretty random. And their appearance isn't regular either. So sometimes there's just one subsection (or number), and sometimes more.
How can I access them? I tried to use  `$datacount = $count($json->result->map)` But it always displays 1. And then I still wouldn't be able to access the subelements of the map key.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: http://php.net/foreach ?

Comment: I was using objects, so I wasn't thinking about foreach! It's so obvious! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have an unknown amount of data in array form, you could iterate your results with a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop:

```
foreach ($json->result->map as $key => $dataArray) {
    // $key will be the numeric key, e.g. 12313214654
    // $dataArray will be the array of data you're after
    foreach ($value as $dataIndex => $data) {
        // $dataIndex is the position of $data within the $dataArray
        // $data is the value you were trying to access with $json->result->map->12313214654[n]
        // You do your work with $data here. 
        print_r($data);
    } 
}
```